# Why does background image not load for flask webpage?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am trying to make a flask webapp but the background image does not show up on the webpage. The css loads perfectly but the background image does not. How can I make it work?

Writing down `body { background-image: url("static/img/Background.png"); font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; }` in a `<style>` block, in HTML file works, but not in CSS, why?
[Directory structure and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFmf.png)

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>

            <div>
                <label for="file">Choose Image</label>
                <input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg, .JPEG" required>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url("static/img/Background.png");
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
```

**Terminal Output**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023 11:38:34] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023 11:38:34] "GET /static/home.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jul/2023 11:38:34] "GET /static/static/img/Background.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: It's because you used a relative URL, so it's relative to the folder that contained the CSS.  Did you notice in the log that it tried to load "/static/static/img/Background.png"?  You either need to make it absolute (`"/static/img/Background.png"`) or remove the base directory (`"img/Background.png"`).

Comment: Thanks, got it! changed url to this -> ```background-image: url("../static/img/Background.png");``` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

try to write this in your css code:

```
background-image: url('Background.png');
```

the css file is in the same directory of the background image you don't need to call the static directory

Comment: changing to this ```background-image: url("../static/img/Background.png");``` worked!